# How to document websocket events or callback in swagger

Tags: api, websocket, documentation, swagger

I have a setup where it is possible to get some resource using standard REST and this is easy documented in swagger. The same resource is pushed to clients using websockets when it has changed, so clients does not have to do a pull on an interval basis.

But how can I document this in swagger? Is it even possible? If not, what other tool do you recommend for documenting both the REST api and the websocket part?

Answer (score 3):

**OpenAPI 3** (aka Swagger 3) has an upgrade in the response formats where they added the concept of callbacks, which allow you to define a webhook. Take a look at this part of the documentation: [response format](https://blog.readme.io/an-example-filled-guide-to-swagger-3-2/#responseformat).

In **Swagger 2** what I use to do is to implement an API method that implements exactly the same I expect from a callback and I just reference it in the original method that waits the callback. So any consumer can at least see the format of message that I'm expecting from them, using the Swagger specification.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult today to find a clear answer on "How to document apis using async communication". It is not only about websocket but also [Server Send events](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) and others....

Today, for Rest specification, there are many famous specifications and the top 3 is:
- [Swagger](https://swagger.io/)
- [RAML](https://raml.org/)
- [API Blue Print](https://apiblueprint.org/)

They are a lot of issue/discussion about a way to document apis using websocket,...

But Swagger is standardizing api specification with the help of the community. It's named [OpenApi](https://www.openapis.org/).

The version 3 of the OpenAPI specifications introduce a way to [document webhook/callback](https://www.openapis.org/category/blog).

Another good specification is [asyncapi.com](https://www.asyncapi.com/) which is going deeper and respect the readeable openApi specs.

Answer (score 0):

The Swagger spec defines a limited set of operations, which you may define for a particular [path object](http://swagger.io/specification/#pathsObject) in your schema. That being said, you are free to step outside of the spec if you only care about documenting your API for human use. Take a look at [WIX docs](http://dev.wix.com/docs/wixhive/http-api/#undefined) for example. It uses a custom `HOOK` definition to document its webhook API and it doesn't pretend to be a valid Swagger spec, which may be just what you need in your case.

Comment: Link is broken...

Comment: Fixed link.....